# Python how to flip coins in a list to get 3 heads in a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the coins to flip at all.

I can populate the list but when the program gets to the flip funtion it crashes.
I have no idea how to get this working.

this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/assignment_3/Main.py", line 46, in <module>
    case 1: coinsThreeInARow()
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/assignment_3/Main.py", line 25, in coinsThreeInARow
    flip = coins[i].flip()
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/assignment_3/Coins.py", line 11, in flip
    while (headsCount < 3):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'headsCount' referenced before assignment
```

here is the code

Main.py

```
from Coins import Coins

currentWinner = 9223372036854775807
    winningCoin = ""
    winnerCount = 0
    num = 1
    coins = []

    answer = int(input("how many coins do you want to flip? "))
    
    #populate list
    for i in range(0, answer):
        ele = num+1
        coins.append(Coins(ele))

    #flip coins in list
    #doesn't work at the moment
    for i in range(0, len(coins)):
        flip = coins[i].flip()
        if (flip < currentWinner):
            currentWinner = flip
            winningCoin = coins[i].getName()
            winnerCount = i
        
    
    print(winningCoin+" is the winner.");
```

Coin.py

```
import math


class Coins:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.name = "c",num
        self.count = 0

    def flip(self):
        self.count
        while (headsCount < 3):
            face = (int)(math.random() * 2);  # range [0, 1]
            self.count+=1
            if (face == 0):
                headsCount+=1
            else:
                headsCount = 0;
        
        print("name: "+self.name+" count: "+self.count);  
        return self.count
    

    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    

    def isHeads(self):
        return (self.face == self.HEADS);
```

Comment: initialize `headCount = 0` in your `def flip()` before the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working thanks to @TomMcLean

here is the working code:

Main.py

```
from Coins import Coins

currentWinner = 9223372036854775807
    winningCoin = ""
    winnerCount = 0
    num = 0
    coins = []

    answer = int(input("how many coins do you want to flip? "))
    
    #populate list
    for i in range(0, answer):
        num+=1
        coins.append(Coins(num))

    #flip coins in list
    #doesn't work at the moment
    for i in range(0, len(coins)):
        flip = coins[i].flip()
        if (flip < currentWinner):
            currentWinner = flip
            winningCoin = coins[i].getName()
            winnerCount = i
        
    
    print(winningCoin," is the winner.")
```

Coin.py

```
import random


class Coins:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.name = "c",num
        self.count = 0
        self.face = 0
        self.HEADS = 0

    def flip(self):
        self.count
        headsCount = 0
        while (headsCount < 3):
            face = (int)(random.randint(0,1));  # range [0, 1]
            self.count+=1
            if (face == 0):
                headsCount+=1
            else:
                headsCount = 0
        
        print("name:",self.name,"count:",self.count)  
        return self.count
    

    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    

    def isHeads(self):
        return (self.face == self.HEADS)
```